# Mounting External Hard Drive on Red Hat

Tags: mount, ntfs, redhat-enterprise-linux

I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 installed on my machine. I am unable to mount an External Hard (NTFS). I have tried several options which are as under:

Option 1
After making a dir `/media/windows`
`mount /dev/sda1 /media/windows/ -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222`

Option 2
`mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/windows

I get this error:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs'

None of these options seems to be working. Here is dmesg of External drive

```
usb 1-3: Product: FreeAgent Go
usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Seagate
usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 2GE28HY5
usb 1-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
scsi6 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
usb-storage: device found at 6
usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
usb-storage: device scan complete
scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  FreeAgent Go     102D PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 1c 00 00 00
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
 sdb: sdb1
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
CE: hpet increasing min_delta_ns to 15000 nsec
```

any other options..

Comment: Does the RH6 kernel have ntfs support?

Comment: issue the command `fdisk -l` to see the partitions on the drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot scratching head & searching finally, i came up with this site
http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/rh6-beta.html
The site (Unknown authenticity) claims that there is no functionality of NTFS support in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Beta. :) And yes he is wrong, you can really see contents of NTFS disk in Red hat 
Just download and install the following package from the under mentioned link:
http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=215580

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to mount `/dev/sdb1` disk instead of `/dev/sda1`